# The "value offset" field of an IFD entry with a rational type can only hold an offset?

Tags: tiff

Consider an IFD entry with a rational type (UNSIGNED RATIONAL or SIGNED RATIONAL).

A value that has a rational type is 8 bytes.

The "value offset" field is 4 bytes.

Therefore, the "value offset" field of an IFD entry with a rational type can only hold an offset (the field can never hold a value).

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: Yes.

Long version:

The TIFF IFD consists of IFD entries, which again consist of 12 bytes, containing, in order:

- 2 byte Tag identifier
- 2 byte Type
- 4 byte Count
- 4 byte Value OR Offset

Quoting from the [TIFF 6.0 spec](http://www.alternatiff.com/resources/TIFF6.pdf):

> **Value/Offset**
>
> To save time and space the Value Offset contains the Value instead of pointing to
> the Value if and only if the Value fits into 4 bytes. If the Value is shorter than 4
> bytes, it is left-justified within the 4-byte Value Offset, i.e., stored in the lowernumbered
> bytes. Whether the Value fits within 4 bytes is determined by the Type
> and Count of the field.

So, as the rational types are always at least 8 bytes long, they can never appear as an "inline" value, only as offsets + value somewhere else in the file.